# Suggest a good story boarding tools for flash development

Tags: flash

Are there any good, easy to use storyboarding tools to build rough animations before passing them on to flash designers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't seen anything Flash specific...but [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/video/en/us/details/1eea789b-c69c-4b09-a13b-b7422c0ff104) from Microsoft would work (just wouldn't be able to re-use the work).

Answer (score 0):

In know this isn't quite what you had in mind, but for story boards I really don't think you can do better than paper.  Seriously - a couple of pages of squares filled with scribbles is amazingly useful, especially if you can wave your arms around as you show the pages to the animators.

But, if you really wanted something to do simple "animatic" type animations with I think the best/easiest tool for that is - Flash.